# React Firebase 9 where is Auth user stored?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm logging in a user using `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` in Firebase version 9.

I'm also setting a user context after a user is logged in:

```
export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged( auth, (user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe()
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentUser
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Finally I'm wrapping my app and routes on the auth context:

```
import { AuthProvider } from "./Auth";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignUp} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Everything works fine. I am able to log in and navigate through any private/protected pages. I can access the user context from any page. I can refresh the page in the browser and I am still logged in. I can log out using Firebase `signOut()` and log back in. All is good.

HOWEVER... where does Firebase and React store the user login? I read that Firebase stores it in Session Storage by default. But when checking Session Storage or Local Storage in the console, there isn't anything saved.

[image]

My guess is that Firebase handles it all through `onAuthStateChanged()` but it is still very mysterious to me... I'm not certain if my code is secure for authentication.

Comment: It's stored in `IndexedDB` right below session storage. Also checkout [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/wgSvjniKPQI)

Comment: @Dharmaraj very interesting! Do you know if this is secure as is?

Comment: Unless someone has physical access to your device and can copy the tokens, everything looks perfectly fine to me. (provided user does not run any malicious scripts in the console).